# Библиотека boost не дружит с Qt

Tags: qt, boost

**Подключил все что мог подключить**

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 // тут библиотеки СИ языка
 #include <iostream> // для оператора cout
 #include <cmath> // библ отвеч за квадрат в СИ
 //--------------------
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cassert>

 #include <math.h> // библ отвеч за квадрат в СИ
 #include <cstring> // библиотека отвечающая за подчет символов строки (char* str) и перевода их (int)
 //#include "math.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <QtGui/QApplication>
 #include <QTextCodec>

 #include <QFile>
 #include <QDebug>
 #include <QDateTimeEdit>
 #include <QDateTime>
 #include <QToolBar>
 #include <QFont>
 #include <QLocale>
 #include <QDebug>
 #include <QDir>
 #include <wchar.h>

 #include <windows.h>
 //--------------------
 #include <boost/filesystem/config.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/exception.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/path_traits.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/string_file.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "1";
    boost::filesystem::path p1 = "notpresent/dirtest";
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(p1, ec);

}

  MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
     delete ui;
}
```

**В .pro файле задал библиотеку bools**

```
  #-------------------------------------------------
  #
  # Project created by QtCreator 2016-09-12T17:30:01
  #
  #-------------------------------------------------

  QT       += core gui

  greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = sohran_wpapku
  TEMPLATE = app
  #-------------------------------------------------
  INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/boost_1_61_0

  LIBS += -L"C:/Qt/boost_1_61_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-10.0/release/link-static/threading-multi" -llibboost_system-vc100-mt-1_61 

   LIBS +=  -L"C:/Qt/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib" \
          -llibboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_61 \
          -llibboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_61
  #-------------------------------------------------

  SOURCES += main.cpp\
             mainwindow.cpp

  HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

  FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**Выдает ошибки**

> mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
>
> mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::codecvt const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@SAABV?$codecvt@GDH@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
>
> release\sohran_wpapku.exe:-1: ошибка: LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

При подключении библиотек boots , они подсвечиваются и предлагаются варианты полного названия. Устанавливал библиотеку boost по методике предлагаемым  на этом сайте http://evilcoderr.blogspot.ru/2013/01/boost-c-vs-2010.html  .
При подключении бустовских библиотек  и следующей компиляции без использования кода функций бустовских библиотек все прекрасно работает (O_o)/.
Что я делаю не так ????

Comment: http://www.evileg.ru/baza-http://www.evileg.ru/baza-znanij/qt/podklyuchenie-biblioteki-boost-v-qt-dlya-kompilyatorov-mingw-i-msvc.htmlznanij/qt/podklyuchenie-biblioteki-boost-v-qt-dlya-kompilyatorov-mingw-i-msvc.html - четко и подробно.

Answer (score 2):

- Уверены что Qt тоже MSVC 2010?
- Пытаетесь подключить буст, который собран в mt, а Qt скорее всего в md, из-за - этого тоже могут быть проблемы.
- После всех манипуляций с pro-файлом, qmake запускали?
- Если не использовать код библиотеки буст, то lib подключаться не будут, хотя они и указаны в pro-файле, потому и нет ошибок компиляции.
- Скорее всего, все что Вы хотите от буст - можно выполнить средствами Qt